# Google Play Services and Unity3D error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I use [official Google plugin for Unity3D](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) to get achievements and lederboards in my game, but when I try to call Google Play Login I got an error:

```
E/GamesNativeSDK﹕ Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.crazylabs.tabreak/app_.gpg.classloader/de80b70ed0da0dfe988a41fa560612ee.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
06-19 18:02:45.058  25436-27013/? E/ValidateServiceOp﹕ Missing metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" in the application tag of the manifest for com.company.game
06-19 18:02:45.105  25436-27012/? E/ValidateServiceOp﹕ Using Google Play games services requires a metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of the manifest for
```

Android manifest:

```
....
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID`, when the error says you need `com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID`.

Also: Make sure you are placing the meta data tag within the `<application>` tag in your manifest.

Lastly, you should be using the app id from the strings folder for the `android:value` attribute. In the end it should look like this:

```
<application>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    ....
</application>
```

Hope that helps!